# Pageviews Count with respect to Campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api, pageviews

I was trying to figure out how many page views each of my Ad Words campaigns are generating to my website via Analytic s.

I followed this path: Traffic Sources > Sources > Campaigns. But there I can only see how many visits, pages/visit, avg. time on site, % New visits and Bounce rate.

To find the number of page views I have to multiply the number of visits by the number of pages/visits, right? But I want to know if it's possible to get this number straight away.

Comment: I think this should rather be asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com (it's not a programming question), but if you look into segments you can select the predefined "paid traffic" segment; this allows you to use all standard reports for the segment of sessions that started via SEA traffic.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].